# Как правильно проверить статус Internet в приложении android?

Tags: java, android

Я во время старта хочу что-бы приложение проверяло подключен ли телефон к интернету, желательно не делать акцент на определенном виде подключения(wi-fi/mobile data). Сейчас я во время запуска приложения проверяю таким способом:

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
        //Получаем статус Интернет
        isInternetPresent = cd.ConnectingToInternet();

        //Проверяем Интернет статус:
        if (!isInternetPresent) {
            showAlertDialog(LoginActivity.this, "Интернет соединение отсутствует",
                    "У вас нет Интернет соединения", false);
        }
        super.onStart();
    }
```

но у меня почему-то если телефон подключен к wi-fi то все-равно выскакивает предупреждение что нету подключения, хотя оно есть. Может нужно отдельно отлавливать подключение к моб. интернету а отдельно по wi-fi? Если кто-то занимался таким вопросом, то буду очень благодарен за помощь и полезные советы.

Comment: Лучший способ проверить подключение - подключиться. Советую пинг к гуглу. Словите `IOException` если подключения нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно советуют решения на базе `ConnectivityManager`, но оно показывает лишь **факт подключения к какой-либо сети**, что не говорит о том, что есть связь с интернетом. Если вы подключитесь к локальной сети по Wi-fi, то метод вернёт `true`, но доступа к интернету может и не быть, т.к. это локальная сеть.

Я бы рекомендовал пинговать адрес, чтоб наверняка сказать, есть ли инет:

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        Process ipProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8");
        int     exitValue = ipProcess.waitFor();
        return (exitValue == 0);
    }
    catch (IOException e)          { e.printStackTrace(); }
    catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    return false;
}
```

Можно прям из UI потока.

Или подключиться попробовать:

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    try {
        int timeoutMs = 1500;
        Socket sock = new Socket();
        SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress("8.8.8.8", 53);

        sock.connect(sockaddr, timeoutMs);
        sock.close();

        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) { return false; }
}
```

Нужен пермишен:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Но это не будет работать в UI потоке, нужно завернуть, к примеру, в `AsyncTask`:

```
class InternetCheck extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean> {

    private Consumer mConsumer;
    public  interface Consumer { void accept(Boolean internet); }

    public  InternetCheck(Consumer consumer) { mConsumer = consumer; execute(); }

    @Override protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) { try {
        Socket sock = new Socket();
        sock.connect(new InetSocketAddress("8.8.8.8", 53), 1500);
        sock.close();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) { return false; } }

    @Override protected void onPostExecute(Boolean internet) { mConsumer.accept(internet); }
}
```

Использовать так:

```
new InternetCheck(internet -> { /* делаем здесь что-то после получения результата */ });
```

Взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-times-out).

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean networkIsConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivity != null ? connectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo() : null;
    return ((networkInfo != null) && networkInfo.isConnected());
}
```